# matplotlib gui imshow coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, imshow

I'm making a GUI using pyqt4 which contains an image displayed by matplotlib's imshow using a 2d array.  If I displayed this with pyplot, the window would show the x, y coordinates of the cursor if I move the mouse over the image.  However, this seems to have disappeared when I embed the imshow in a pyqt GUI.  Is there a way that I can get a mouse event to call some function which returns those x, y coordinates (or better yet, the indexes of that 2d array) of the point that the mouse is hovering over?

**EDIT:** I found documentation for wx, but I still have no idea how to do this for my GUI. [wxcursor_demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/user_interfaces/wxcursor_demo.html)

If it helps, here is how I'm embedding the imshow plot.  First, I create a base canvas class, then from that I create a class for the imshow:

```
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100, projection = None):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (width, height), dpi = dpi)
        if projection:
            self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)
        else:
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.axes.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)
        self.axes.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 8)
        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class TopView(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axes)
        self.cax = self.divider.append_axes("bottom", size = "5%", pad = 0.2)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.top = self.axes.imshow(zarr, interpolation = 'none', extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], origin = 'lower')
        self.top.set_cmap('nipy_spectral')
        self.top.set_clim(vmin = pltMin, vmax = pltMax)
```

Then, in the main window, I create the object and place it in the grid layout:

```
tv = TopView(self.main_widget, width = 4, height = 3, dpi = 100)
self.g.addWidget(tv, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib uses its own event so that they are independent of the UI toolkits (wx-windows, Qt, etc). Therefore the [wxcursor_demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/user_interfaces/wxcursor_demo.html) is easily adapted to Qt, as is your case.

First add the following line to the constructor of your `Canvas` class

```
self.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.mouse_moved)
```

This will call the mouse_moved method every time the mouse is in motion.

In the `mouse_moved` method you can emit a Qt signal that is connected to a widget that knows how to display the mouse coordinates. Something like this:

```
def mouse_moved(self, mouse_event):
    if mouse_event.inaxes:
        x, y = mouse_event.xdata, mouse_event.ydata
        self.mouse_moved_signal.emit(x,y)
```

Of course you'll have to define the `mouse_moved_signal` in the `Canvas` constructor as well. Note that the `mouse_event` parameter is a [Matplotlib event](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent), not a Qt event.

I recommend that you read the [chapter about events](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/event_handling.html) in the Matplotlib documentation to understand what is possible.